# Is your commander still a "commander" if it gets turned face down?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

Does your commander still count as being your commander if it is turned face down?

For example, I have my commander on the battlefield and my opponent plays [Ixidron](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ixidron). Ixidron then turns my commander face down.

From Gatherer:

> Creatures turned face down by Ixidron are 2/2 creatures with no text,
> no name, no subtypes, no expansion symbol, and no mana cost.

Will my face down commander still:

- deal commander damage?
- enable "Lieutenant" abilities?

Is the result different if my commander is turned face down by another means?

Comment: Open to suggestions for a clearer title on this question

Comment: I think the title is just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just discovered that this exact circumstance is described in the rules. It will remain your commander.

> 903.3. Each deck has a legendary creature card designated as its commander. This designation is not a characteristic of the object
>   represented by the card; rather, it is an attribute of the card
>   itself. The card retains this designation even when it changes zones.
>
> Example: **A commander that’s been turned face down (due to Ixidron’s
>   effect, for example) is still a commander.** A commander that’s copying
>   another card (due to Cytoshape’s effect, for example) is still a
>   commander. A permanent that’s copying a commander (such as a Body
>   Double, for example, copying a commander in a player’s graveyard) is
>   not a commander.

Comment: It makes me wonder what would happen if Akroma, Angel of Fury is your commander and then ended up in your hand somehow and you played it face down. Then there is no way of knowing that it is actually your commander

Comment: @IvoBeckers, It would still be your commander. I suppose it would require _revealing_ the face-down card to prove that fact if you actually connected with her while face-down, though. (Then again, how many morph cards really get played in mono-red?)

Comment: @IvoBeckers I think that's worthy of its own separate question. If you choose not to reveal the hidden information, does it not count as your commander? Can you deal commander damage to your opponent without them knowing it?